# Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. reanimated carousel

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

new to react native, and i got this error:

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes.

expo project with typescript. my app was running fine before i used react-native-reanimated-carousel.

my code is:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import styleHome from "../styles/stylesHome";
import stylePadrao from "../styles/stylesDefault";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Montserrat_400Regular } from "@expo-google-fonts/montserrat";
import Carousel from "react-native-reanimated-carousel";

function TelaPrincipal() {
  useFonts({
    Montserrat_400Regular,
  });

  const ImageArray = [
    {
      id: 1,
      url: "https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/procedure/proc_par/step_1/step_par/multi_column/col-50-50-c2/image/BW-properties.jpg.img.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      url: "https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/procedure/proc_par/step_1/step_par/multi_column/col-50-50-c2/image/BW-properties.jpg.img.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      url: "https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/procedure/proc_par/step_1/step_par/multi_column/col-50-50-c2/image/BW-properties.jpg.img.jpg",
    },
  ];

  function SlideBanner() {
    return (
      <Carousel
        loop
        width={80}
        height={20}
        autoPlay={true}
        data={[ImageArray]}
        scrollAnimationDuration={1500}
        onSnapToItem={(index) => console.log("current index: " + index)}
        renderItem={({ index }) => (
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              borderWidth: 1,
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: 30 }}>{index}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={stylePadrao.style}>
        <View style={styleHome.alignBtnRow}>
          <View style={styleHome.alignBtn}>
            <Pressable style={styleHome.btn}>
              <Text
                style={{ fontFamily: "Montserrat_400Regular", fontSize: 19 }}
              >
                Delivery
              </Text>
            </Pressable>

            <Pressable style={styleHome.btn}>
              <Text
                style={{ fontFamily: "Montserrat_400Regular", fontSize: 19 }}
              >
                Reserva
              </Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styleHome.bannerStyle}>
          <SlideBanner />
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default TelaPrincipal;
```

tried clearing the cache but it didnt work.